# bash: What are the purposes of the two colons in echo ${addr:$i:2}?

Tags: bash

Can someone explain the meaning of the following bash script? I am mainly confused about the echo usage. What are the purposes of the two colons?

```
for addr in $@; do
    for i in $(seq 8 -2 2); do echo -ne "\x${addr:$i:2}"; done
done
```

Comment: Do you mean the two colons in here `{addr:$i:2}`?

Comment: ${var:x:y} allows you to get a substring of the variable content

Comment: This is... pretty awful code, by the way. `in $@` is exactly equivalent to `in $*`, which is *not at all* what the original author presumably wanted which is `in "$@"`, or just `for addr; do`

Comment: and `echo -ne` is a horrible practice itself: `echo -e` is disallowed by the POSIX spec for `echo` (which allows but does not specify behavior for `-n`). The best-practices alternative if one *really* needed `-e` is `printf %b`, but there's nothing here that would require `-e`'s behavior.

Comment: This might help: `man bash | sed -n '/{[^:]\+:[^:]\+:[^}]\+}/,/^$/p'`

Comment: Next time, try reading the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) before asking. Have a look at [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). "${parameter:offset:length} This is referred to as Substring Expansion. It expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset. ..."

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
echo -ne "\x${addr:$i:2}"
```

- The `-n` option instructs `echo` to not output a newline at the end of the line.
- The `-e` instructs `echo` to treat the `\x` in its string as a prefix for an "eight-bit character whose value is given as a 2-character hexadecimal number" (adapted from the manual).
- The `${addr:$i:2}` is "substring expansion". It will give you the 2-character substring from offset `$i` in the string "`$addr`" (which will probably be the hexadecimal number that is going to be converted into that eight-bit character).

**EDIT**: See comments from user @CharlesDuffy below about the standard (non-)conformance of the `echo` built-in command in `bash`, the options that are likely to *break* this code if they are set, and an alternative solution using `printf` that will make the code much more robust would want to update it.

Comment: Which manual? Per the POSIX spec for `echo`, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, any `echo` which does anything but print `-e` on its output when given `-e` on its input is noncompliant, and `printf %b` is the standards-compliant alternative.

Comment: Granted, the bash implementation of echo is noncompliant out-of-the-box, but if both `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are set it conforms (breaking the OP's code).

Comment: Sure, but this isn't just a place where bash's behavior is extended -- an *extension* is something that's implementing new behavior in space that POSIX doesn't specify. This is nonconformance to something that POSIX *did* clearly specify, and it's nonconformance *that can be turned off*, making it code that's needlessly dependent on runtime parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature of Bash string substitution, not of `echo`. The notation `${var:start:length}` extracts a substring of the variable `var` starting at character *start* and containing a substring of *length.*

The character `:` is called *colon;* the *semicolon* looks like this: `;`

Answer (score 1):

In here the `${addr:$i:2}` extracts the chars in string `$addr` from postion `$i` up to `$i+2`

The index `-2` makes no sense to me as it will always return the full string if calles with a negative start position.

Finally it will output:
Chars 8 up to 10 and 2 up to 4 for all words that are passed as an argument.